# Postsharp with obfuscated assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, postsharp, obfuscar

I'm using visual studio 2015 (C#) with Postsharp
The code that i'm using is obfuscated
locally on my machine everything is being complied and working as expected.
When i'm trying to check in/build changes to the server i failed :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Nobody but you can see your screen. Make a complete question or no one can help.

Comment: What am i missing?

Comment: How about logs, the errors you are seeing? etc